# Camera fails to start in android

Tags: android, camera

I have made a camera demo application in android. It was working fine on a button click event. But now I want to open the camera when activity starts and its not working. It fails with an error

> Failed to connect to camera service

Please have a look at my code and save me. My code is as below:

**code**

```
        surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView1);
        surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

        rawCallback = new PictureCallback() {
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                Log.d("Log", "onPictureTaken - raw");
            }
        };

        /** Handles data for jpeg picture */
        shutterCallback = new ShutterCallback() {
            public void onShutter() {
                Log.i("Log", "onShutter'd");
            }
        };
        jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {
            @SuppressLint("NewApi")
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                FileOutputStream outStream = null;
                try {
                    outStream = new FileOutputStream(String.format(
                            "/sdcard/%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis()));
                    outStream.write(data);
                    outStream.close();
                    Log.d("Log", "onPictureTaken - wrote bytes: " + data.length);

                    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    options.inMutable = true;
                    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length,
                            options);

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                }
                Log.d("Log", "onPictureTaken - jpeg");
            }
        };

        start_camera();

private void start_camera() {
        try {
            releaseCameraAndPreview();
            camera = Camera.open();
            camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            Log.e(tag, "init_camera: " + e);
            return;
        }

        param = camera.getParameters();
        param.set("jpeg-quality", 100);
        camera.setParameters(param);
        // modify parameter

        try {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            camera.startPreview();
            // camera.takePicture(shutter, raw, jpeg)
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(tag, "init_camera: " + e);
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: have you enabled camera permissions in your manifest ?

Comment: I don't think this is because of your code. Have you tried restarting your phone. It happens to me quite some times.

Comment: @user2469133-tried with no luck..!

Comment: @user2469133-yes of course..i said it was working when i am starting camera on a button click.

Comment: `Failed to connect to camera service`. Where does it say so?

Comment: @greenapps-when i open camera in acitivty start